# importing from excel to listbox

Tags: vb.net, excel, listbox, importerror, import-from-excel

I'm having an break error while trying to import column from excel to my listbox in vb.net form

the problem is after importing all the items inside the column successfuly to the listbox . A break error shown up and close the program. 
here is the break error

```
     An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred  
     in System.Windows.Forms.dll     
     Additional information: Value cannot be null))
```

and here is my code

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
Dim oExcel As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook As Object = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.xlsx")
Dim oSheet As Object = oBook.Worksheets(1)
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As String
For i = 0 To AscW(ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString()(i = i + 1))

        cell = "E" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
        cell = oSheet.Range(cell).Value
        ListBox1.Items.Add(cell)

    Next
    oExcel.Quit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you test if cell is null after `cell = oSheet.Range(cell).Value` ?

Comment: Can you explain more please

Comment: Test the value of `cell` before adding it in to the ListBox1 Items collection.

Comment: i did. but same error occur

Comment: If you step through the code in your debugger, on which line does the error occur?

Comment: here : ListBox1.Items.Add(cell)

Comment: Update the code above to show how you're testing for null before adding.

Comment: It seems i was testing in the wrong way .. I edit it as you told me and now working fine. Thank you very much for the kind support